# Why is this my jQuery keypress() event not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, triggers

I have a text box

```
<input id="textinput" type="text" name="text_input" value=""/>
```

and a properly linked (did a console.log in the document ready function and it worked) jquery file

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    console.log("hi");

});

$( '#textinput' ).keypress(function() {

    var tag_text = $('#textinput').val();
    console.log("key pressed");

});
```

[As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything properly.](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) However, I am obviously not doing something right.

My goal is to make it so that whenever a letter/character (or any key, really) is pressed with focus on the textinput textbox, an event will trigger.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [Your code works.](http://jsfiddle.net/ja05jhLu/)

Comment: Have you made sure to include jQuery properly? What error do you get in the console?

Comment: Why did you put the console.log in a document ready event but not the keypress code?

Comment: You have to place your `keypress` handler into document ready

Comment: @Juhana Because my understanding of events in jQuery is horrendous...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `keypress` function inside the `$(document).ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("hi");

    $( '#textinput' ).keypress(function() {

        var tag_text = $(this).val();
        console.log("key pressed");

    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf78gs4s/)

Comment: My understanding of events in javascript is bad and I should feel bad... I figured they would be independent of the document being "ready" and thus had to live outside the function.  Guess I should do some more learning about jquery.

Comment: Haha, you effectively want the document to be 'ready' before it starts doing anything. That's the way I see it. Most things will go inside the `document.ready` function. We're always here to help! @xcdemon05

Answer (score 3):

Try binding the keypress event in the `$(document).ready()` function. Your code works as intended.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( '#textinput' ).keypress(function() {
        var tag_text = $('#textinput').val();
        console.log("key pressed");
    });

});
```